# Increment inside the for loop and outside the for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, post-increment

in the following loop which **i++** will be executed first?the one which is inside the for loop or the one at line no 3?

```
enter code here

1.for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
2.a[i] = a[i] + 1;
3.i++;
4.}
```

Comment: Questions about solving homework must demonstrate effort, see [help/on-topic].

Comment: Trick question, the first time through the loop its the inside, all other times it is in the FOR declaration, you really don't have a i++ "outside of the loop", Declaration, cond check, skips the iteration. then the inside scope runs, then i is incremented again. So you get one increment first time entering the loop, for every time after that it is just like having i++; twice in a row inside the scope.  You can switch that up with ++i . . . .

Answer (score 1):

The one inside the loop is executed first.  The one in the loop declaration is always executed at the end of each loop before it starts its next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Is it difficult to test it yourself?:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) 
    {
        printf("i before increment = %d\n", i);
        i++;
        printf("i after increment = %d\n", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Run and test it yourself
https://ideone.com/N76Q2n

and everything will be clear.